# script to disable one of the external screens?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, configuration

Is there a way to write the commands down to a script that would disable one of the external screens in an Ubuntu 12.04 Virtualbox machine, every time the Windows 7 laptop is plugged to the two external screens I have?

I find myself manually disabling the screen through "System Settings" and I would like to be able to speed up this process by having it written in a script. Ideally, the script would listen to the list of connected monitors and kick in every time the second monitor is plugged in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use an script called monitor1 which disables my secondary monitor. It contains  this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#final()
#coding=utf8

# Desactiva el monitor secundari:

xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --off
```

Of course, you'll have to change DVI-I-1 with the name of the  monitor you want to disable. To enable both monitors I use other script called monitor2:

```
#!/bin/sh
#final()
#coding=utf8

# Activa el monitor secundari com extensió del primari:

xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1280x1024 --noprimary --pos 1024x0
```

This re-activates the secondary monitor and places it to the top right of the primary monitor.

To find out which monitors do you have (which names) you can use  xrandr:

```
xrandr --current
```

For instance, mine looks  like this:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2646 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
DVI-I-1 connected 1280x1024+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 352mm x 264mm
```

As you can see, I have a primary monitor always on and a secondary one I turn off when  playing games on fullscreen, specially with wine.

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: De res:) El menú a unity està massa amagat xD